# how to use addObject

Tags: game-engine

I have the object I am spawning on a separate layer from what I read that is correct, but I am having errors that the key is not in the list...double checked names and everything. Can anyone maybe see something I do not?

here is the error
KeyError: "CList[key]: ''breadcrumb'' key not in list"
I assume it thinks there is no object with that name

and the code I used below

```
import bge
```

def main():

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

node = scene.objects['breadcrumb']
life_time = 5
#scene.addObject(object,loc,duration) *duration is in frames
if own['nodeSpawnTimer'] >= 5 and own['nodeCount'] <= 20:
    scene.addObject(node,own.worldPosition, life_time)
    own['nodeCount'] += 1
    own['nodeSpawnTimer'] = 0
```

main()

Answer (score 3):

To addObject() the **object has to be in an inactive layer.**
[image]

you need to use:

```
import bge
def main():

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

node = scene.objectsInactive['breadcrumb']
life_time = 15
#scene.addObject(object,loc,duration) *duration is in frames
if own['nodeSpawnTimer'] >= 5 and own['nodeCount'] <= 20:
    obj =scene.addObject(node,own, life_time)
    own['nodeCount'] += 1
    own['nodeSpawnTimer'] = 0
```

**Related [Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_Scene.html?highlight=objectsinactive#bge.types.KX_Scene.objectsInactive)**

Comment: thanks, I should have returned sooner I received an answer on blender artists that pointed me to 'objectsInactive'.